# Queries to find places within a given lat/lng

Tags: php, mysql, sql, distance, latitude-longitude

So I'm trying to display lists of places within a range of the given lat/lng. I have no problem with this:

Places within one mile
(list of places...)

Using something like

```
SELECT * FROM places WHERE lat < $latmax AND lat > $latmin AND lng < $lngmax AND lng > $lngmin
```

But then I want to list places within two miles, BUT not within one mile -- that is, I don't want to repeat the results from the first query.

Here's one version of what I've tried:

```
$milesperdegree = 0.868976242 / 60.0 * 1.2;

// 1 mile -- this works
$degrees = $milesperdegree * 1;
$latmin = $lat - $degrees;
$latmax = $lat + $degrees;
$lngmin = $lng - $degrees;
$lngmax = $lng + $degrees;

$query = "SELECT * FROM places WHERE lat < $latmax AND lat > $latmin AND lng < $lngmax AND lng > $lngmin";

// 2 miles -- this doesn't work
$degrees_2 = $milesperdegree * 2;
$latmin_2 = $lat - $degrees_2;
$latmax_2 = $lat + $degrees_2;
$lngmin_2 = $lat - $degrees_2;
$lngmax_2 = $lat + $degrees_2;

$query = "SELECT * FROM places WHERE ";
$query .= "lat BETWEEN $latmax AND $latmax_2 AND lng BETWEEN $lngmax AND $lngmax_2 OR ";
$query .= "lat BETWEEN $latmin AND $latmin_2 AND lng BETWEEN $lngmin AND $lngmin_2 OR ";
$query .= "lat BETWEEN $latmax AND $latmax_2 AND lng BETWEEN $lngmin AND $lngmin_2 OR ";
$query .= "lat BETWEEN $latmin AND $latmin_2 AND lng BETWEEN $lngmax AND $lngmax_2";
```

That's not doing it. I'm guessing it's just some logic I can't wrap my head around on Sunday afternoon, but I'm probably doing something else wrong too. Any input is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you realize that this script just makes a box around the point (instead of a circle)? Also, $milesperdegree is a function (mathematically speaking) of latitude. There's a nice script for this - although in JavaScript - [link](http://www.fas.org/news/reference/calc/degree.html)

Comment: I did not realize the circle/square bit. And I guess the longitude variables would be $lng +/- x miles, rather than $milesperdegree?

Comment: As Earth is not a perfect sphere, the length of a degree is not fixed. If your scripts operates just on a small area (like a city), you can work with an average **for that area**. Otherwise more math is needed for precision. See [latitude](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latitude#Degree_length) and [longitude](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longitude#Degree_length) in Wikipedia.

Comment: As for the circle/square part - a simple application of the Pythagorean theorem would fix that.

Comment: Btw, +1 for the `BETWEEN ... AND`, didn't know that one ;)

Comment: @nickfindley, I've added a "circle" solution, see my answer.

Comment: @Czechnology Actually the distance between degrees has nothing to do with the earth not being a perfect sphere (while that does have a tiny effect it's pretty negligible).  It's more a function of distance from the centre.  The centre of the circle is the north/south pole.  The length of any arc of x degrees increases with distance from the centre.  Should be clear by looking at this diagram of a protractor: http://www.farlaboratories.com/dyna-a-prot.html

Comment: @Endophage, of course, you're absolutely right, that's the main reason for that. I was thinking of miles per degree of latitude where the differences are mainly because of the shape of the earth. But of course, angle from the equator/poles is much more significant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We implement it more or less like the code below (disclaimer:  I snipped this out of a file and deleted the code that was irrelevant to the problem at hand.  I didn't run this, but you should be able to get the idea.

```
$maxLat = $city->latitude + ($max_distance / 69); // 69 Miles/Degree
$minLat = $city->latitude - ($max_distance / 69);

$maxLon = $city->longitude + ($max_distance / (69.172 * cos($city->latitude * 0.0174533)));
$minLon = $city->longitude - ($max_distance / (69.172 * cos($city->latitude * 0.0174533)));

// Simplify terms to speed query
$originLatRadCos = cos($city->latitude * 0.0174533);
$originLatRadSin = sin($city->latitude * 0.0174533);
$originLonRad = $city->longitude * 0.0174533;

$city_distance_query = "
SELECT city_id, 
  3963 * acos(($originLatRadSin * sin( latitude * 0.0174533)) + 
  ($originLatRadCos * cos(latitude * 0.0174533) * cos((longitude * 0.0174533) -
  $originLonRad))) AS distanceFromOrigin
FROM cities
WHERE
 latitude < $maxLat AND latitude > $minLat AND longitude < $maxLon AND longitude > $minLon";
```

The rest of the query

```
SELECT cities.city_name, CityDistance.distanceFromOrigin,
FROM cities 
INNER JOIN ($city_distance_query) AS CityDistance ON CityDistance.city_id=cities.city_id
WHERE (distanceFromOrigin < $distance OR distanceFromOrigin IS NULL)
```

Comment: Certainly wouldn't have guessed that. Thanks all.

Comment: Thank you very much for the post. Saved me a lot!
Very easily adapted and clear.

Answer (score 2):

I think you're missing some brackets and have the logical operators a bit mixed up. How about this.

```
$query  = "SELECT * FROM places WHERE ";
$query .= "((lat BETWEEN $latmin_2 AND $latmax_2) AND NOT (lat BETWEEN $latmin AND $latmax)) AND ";
$query .= "((lng BETWEEN $lngmin_2 AND $lngmax_2) AND NOT (lng BETWEEN $lngmin AND $lngmax)) AND ";
```

**EDIT**

To solve the circle/square problem:

```
$query  = "SELECT * FROM places WHERE ";
$query .= "(POW((lat - $lat) * $avgMilesPerLatDeg,2) + ".
           "POW((lng - $lng) * $avgMilesPerLngDeg,2) BETWEEN 1 AND 4)";
// the four at the end is 2 squared
```

I would suggest using this approach if your app is not large-scale (geographically speaking) and the averages produce acceptable results. Calculating the *real* distance takes longer to compute and the difference might not be that big. This is up to you and your application's goal.

Comment: Getting there! But I have to admit I don't quite understand what's going on, I guess mathematically at least. What would that query be to get the places between two and three miles out?

Comment: The three miles out would be the farthest I'd go in this app -- just being roughly in the neighborhood is good enough. Though I appreciate the knowledge being dropped for future use.

Comment: @nickfindley, It's really a just a pythagorean `a^2 + b^2 = c^2`, in our case `n <= (x-a)^2 + (y-b)^2 <= m`. So for places between two and three miles you need `... BETWEEN POW(2,2) AND POW(3,2)` which is equivalent to `... BETWEEN 4 AND 9`

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I think you need: [Calculate distance in MySQL using lat/lng](http://zcentric.com/2010/03/11/calculate-distance-in-mysql-with-latitude-and-longitude/). This will give you a circle, and an ability to have exclusion you need.

Follow the steps described in a post, but instead of

```
HAVING `distance`<= 10
```

You will need to put

```
HAVING `distance` BETWEEN 1 AND 2
```

This will give you stuff within the range.

PS: If you have a database with large number of records - you will need to benchmark how would it perform, and do some optimization (if performance is not acceptable)