# Calculating gps coordinate radius

Tags: php, mysql, gps, coordinates

I have this coordinates:

lat: 45.815005
lon: 15.978501

and i have mysql table with lat and lon coordinates stored as float

what i need is to get all coordinate in 500 meters around me?

so basicly my problem is to add X meters to my coordinate location

Also: how can i separate coordinate 45.815005 (45 | 81 | 50 | 05 ???) so i can store them in mysql using indexes for quicker search?

Comment: Please see this question and answers: [Queries to find places within a given lat/lng](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5135488/queries-to-find-places-within-a-given-lat-lng)

Answer (score 0):

MySQL supports a [**spatial extension**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/spatial-extensions.html) *(quoting)* :

> MySQL supports spatial extensions to
>   enable the generation, storage, and
>   analysis of geographic features.

Using those, instead of storing coordinates your own way, might help, when it comes to geographical manipulations.

Comment: i have try spatial extension but is really slow with large amount od data. I would like to use indexed separated coordinates.